# AS3 Child Index in relation to Stage

Tags: actionscript-3

I m currently moving my CPU image post processing frame from AS2 to AS3. I used an array to handle all the objects that need to be rendered each frame.
I sort the array by the object's depth on _root, and then render them all onto one bitmapdata in order to draw them in the correct order.

In my AS3 game project I used displayobjectcontainers to handle "depths". for example I have multiple movieclips acting as containers on MovieClip(root), and then add the child to those movieclips to sort them. I also have other child containers inside those containers, forming an hierarchy.

But now I find it hard to sort the render list array because I cannot simply input an absolute "depth" value for the object. I use parent.getChildIndex, but this just gives me the index of the child in one of those containers.

Ofcourse you can make a big function and finally sort the array, but is there anyway to give the object's absolute index in relation to the root/stage?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, which will start at a given `DisplayObjectContainer` and generate a list of all descendants in order of depth:

```
function collateChildren(container:DisplayObjectContainer):Vector.<DisplayObject>
{
    var list:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new <DisplayObject>[];
    for(var i:int = 0; i < container.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var child:DisplayObject = container.getChildAt(i);
        if(child is DisplayObjectContainer && (child as DisplayObjectContainer).numChildren > 0)
        {
            // Target contains additional children.
            list = list.concat(collateChildren(child as DisplayObjectContainer));
        }
        else
        {
            // Target is a child.
            list.push(child);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

This will not include children who contain other children, and can be used like:

```
var children:Vector.<DisplayObject> = collateChildren(stage);
trace(children);
```

Comment: Thank you. If I do it everyframe, will this affect performance? say we have about 250 children in total.

Comment: @TommyX 250 children should be fine. If you're concerned, you can greatly reduce the amount of times you need to run this by only doing it when you add or remove a child.

Comment: Ok. I think I ll have this in my render function and run everytime when the render function detects change in render list. thanks.

Comment: @TommyX That sounds wise :-)

Comment: Oh and just asking, Do you have knowledge in Stage3D and AGAL Shader code writing?

Comment: @TommyX No, unfortunately that level of programming is outside of my capabilities at this stage. I *do* do game development using Starling, but I don't tamper with the lower level stuff myself.

Comment: I m choosing starling for school game making club. I should probably start another question but, can starling work well in Flash Pro IDE?

Comment: @TommyX Yes, I have had good results with Starling. I actually am working on a game engine using Starling and Box2D which you can follow here: https://github.com/MartyWallace/Exalted/tree/master/Source/exalted

Comment: Sounds fantastic. Does it works like starling (mimics flash display object style) ? Is the framework working as of now? any instructions?

Comment: @TommyX It uses Starling for its display architecture, so it's exactly the same. There is no documentation currently and there are likely small bugs. I could spend time to write a blog post about how to get it working if you were interested, but it might cause more headaches than its worth at this stage. Maybe bookmark it and check up on it every now and then.

Comment: Will do. just need the blog url for bookmark and I ll check it frequently. IDE works best for guys in the club as graphic designers.

Comment: @TommyX You can create sprite sheets which are compatible with Starling via Flash CS6 or later: http://tv.adobe.com/watch/cs6-creative-cloud-feature-tour-for-web/generating-sprite-sheets-using-flash-professional-cs6/ If you just bookmark that repository on GitHub, I plan to add a walkthrough in the README section when it's stable.

Answer (score 0):

A game world would consist of some layers,like role layer, map layer, and each layer has it's depth in the game world. When you try to add some displayobjects to the world, add the displayobjects  to the targe layer.

At most time, the layer count won't be large, like 5 or 6. So you can draw the objects on each layer by layer depth.

Comment: Thanks, what you ve said is exactly what I m doing. Also my game world contains lots of explosions, bullets and particles, thats why it became a interference.